# How would I split up user input into a char and an integer?

Tags: c++

I am working on a project where I have to parse data from user input.

```
#include <iostream>   // for cin and cout
#include <iomanip>    // for setw()
#include <cctype>     // for toupper()
using namespace std;


int main(){

string playerInput;

cin >> playerInput; 
//Player would input strings like C13,C 6, I1, Z  16, etc...




}
return 0;
```

I've tried something like this, which kinda works but only if the letter proceeds the number in the string.

```
int myNr = std::stoi(playerInput);
```

What my end goal is to grab the letter and number from the string, and place them in a char variable and a integer variable respectively. I am stuck on how to proceed from here and could use some help, thanks!

Comment: Can you show an input/output example? Do you have to read multiple comma separated strings? Are they on separate lines?

Comment: A lot depends on how much you can trust the precision of the input.  If it is human input, it may miss a space or a comma or such.  How tolerant do you want your input parser to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the simplest and the shortest way to achieve that (it also ignores spaces and tabs):

```
int main() {
    char ch;
    int n;
    cin >> ch >> n;

    cout << "ch = " << ch << ", n = " << n << endl;
}
```

I think that other answers are a bit overcomplicated.

Comment: This is the simplest one and it works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea in using `std::stoi`. My code expands your approach:

```cpp
string playerInput;
getline(cin, playerInput);

char c1 = playerInput[0];
int num = stoi(playerInput.substr(1));
```

The above code receives an input `string`, then takes out the first character and uses `std::stoi` on the rest of the string.

Note that I use `std::getline` to account for the possibility of there being spaces in the input. If you are doing this repeatedly, you will need to add `cin.ignore()` after each `getline()` statement. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction) for more info.

Comment: How would I go about checking the playerInput? For example, if playerInput = "Cz14" It will spit out an invalid argument error code.

Comment: Your question implied that the user input would only consist of *one* char and then a number. If the number of chars varies, then let me know and I'll update my answer.

Comment: In fact, if the number of `chars` varies, then none of the posted answers would work. We all assumed that the input string only contained one `char`: the first character.

Answer (score 1):

You could do like what you had:

```
    char letter = playerInput.front();
    playerInput.erase(0);

    int number = std::stoi(playerInput);
```

Of course, that doesn't allow for spaces. Removing spaces can be quite tedious, but it could be done like:

```
    playerInput.erase(
            std::remove_if(
                begin(playerInput), end(playerInput),
                [](uint8_t ch) { return std::isspace(ch); }),
            end(playerInput));
```

### Full Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73b1cf89c84bf5c0)**

```
#include <cctype>   // for toupper()
#include <iomanip>  // for setw()
#include <iostream> // for cin and cout
#include <algorithm> // for remove_if

static bool ignorable(uint8_t ch) {
    return std::isspace(ch)
        || std::ispunct(ch);
}

int main() {
    std::string playerInput;

    while (getline(std::cin, playerInput)) {
        playerInput.erase(
                std::remove_if(
                    begin(playerInput), end(playerInput),
                    ignorable),
                end(playerInput));
                
        if (playerInput.empty())
            continue;

        char letter = playerInput.front();
        playerInput.erase(begin(playerInput));

        int number = std::stoi(playerInput);

        std::cout << "Got: " << letter << " with " << number << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Got: C with 13
Got: C with 6
Got: I with 1
Got: Z with 16
```

Comment: Added the [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73b1cf89c84bf5c0)

Comment: For contrast, with an actual input parser: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1960383848797d67)**

Answer (score 0):

`std::cin` stops reading input when it encounters a space. You can use `std::getline()` if your input has spaces. To parse your string, you should check out [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream). It allows you to read from a string as if it were a stream like `std::cin`.

```
#include <iostream>   // for cin and cout
#include <iomanip>    // for setw()
#include <cctype>     // for toupper()
#include <sstream>

int main(){

std::string playerInput;
int i;
char c;
 std::getline(std::cin, playerInput); // Remove trailing newline
 std::getline(std::cin, playerInput);
//Player would input strings like C13,C 6, I1, Z  16, etc...
 
//String Stream
std::stringstream playerInputStream(playerInput);
//Read as if you were reading through cin
 playerInputStream >> c; // 
 playerInputStream >> i;



}
return 0;
```